# Can we port any game written in C++ with SDL to Android platform or we would need to change some codes too?

Tags: c++, android, sdl, sdl2

Just wanted to lean a cross-platform library!!

Since SDL library supports iOS too..

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot port any ol' game written in C++/SDL to another platform.

Most games only use SDL for a few small bits (windowing and input) and rely on a great deal of other platform-specific code for rendering, audio, file I/O, threading, debug facilities, networking, etc.

SDL does provide tools for those services, and some SDL games will be pure SDL with no other external dependencies, but as SDL's facilities in those areas is very weak those games are rare.

Even with pure SDL, Android and iOS use different C++ compilers and have numerous other minor differences that makes porting even well-written cross-platform applications more involved than just recompiling.